# How to cancel "resetting this pc"

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I selected "Reset this PC" in the Windows 10 boot menu (the one that lets me choose between Windows 7 and Windows 10). I did this while my Win7 thumbdrive was inserted, with the hope that this would remove Windows 10.

However, now that I'm at the "resetting this pc" progress screen, the Win10 logo is visible, which to me means that I'm not removing Windows 10. How do I cancel the process so I can try some other way? I don't want to wait 2 more hours.

Btw I know that my actions don't make much sense as described, but they seemed a good idea at the time :)

Comment: You can't cancel. And that feature resets to factory defaults meaning the factory default OS.

Comment: @user931000 That's factually inaccurate - _Reset This PC_ will "reset" the OS to a clean install state of the current OS version installed. Prior to v1809 _(might be v1803)_, it was performed using an `install.wim` for the version of Windows installed, however v1809 _(might be v1803)_ and later uses the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`]. What you're speaking about is a factory restore from an OEM's factory reserved partition that houses a WIM image [`.wim`] or split-WIM images (`.swm`) of the state the PC was in when it left the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to just force-shut down the PC (by holding the power button). Now I booted again, and I get "Windows is installing". So I don't think I broke anything.

Comment: You'll soon run into random issues. Better install it clean.

Comment: So what's the situation now? Do you still want to cancel or do you intend to wait for it to finish?

Comment: @harrymc: I got out of the hellish "resetting this pc" thing, with no apparent consequences, so I'm pretty happy with the situation now. :)

Comment: "Windows is installing" means that the Reset is going through. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @harrymc: Reset would've taken about 2 more hours. "Windows is installing" took 20 minutes, because it didn't have to go through every byte on the HDD and shred the data on it.